# How do I install the binary ATI graphics driver?

Tags: installation, drivers, ati

I have been trying all day to get a driver up and running on my quad core 64b machine runing 11.10 32b.
I put the driver into downloads and eventually got it permission.
However I am not there yet.

The below commands did not work:

```
chmod u+x ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run
```

It results in:

```
sh: Cant open sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run
```

Catalyst gives me:

```
For further configuration of the driver, please run anticonfig from a terminal or AMD CCC:LE from desktop Manager Menu.
```

I ran `sudo aticonfig --initial` after `antony@antony` and got "command not found". 
Running `sudo aticonfig --initial`  gives:

```
sudo ati-config: command not found
```

Can someone see where I am going wrong? Or where to next?

Comment: Ugh, ATI/AMD drivers aren't working very well on Ubuntu. I'm having similar problems.

Comment: Let me know if you get a cure so far after a week I can only run notebook connected to a HDMI

Comment: @Lekenstyeyn did you remove your comment and my answer. why? Thanks

Comment: @Antony My answer was targetting the wrong problem which is why I added a new answer.

Comment: @Daniel0108 see now Lekenstyeyn helped me solve mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've downloaded the file and saved it to the `Downloads` directory, you need to make sure that you run the commands from that folder.

If you first open a terminal, you'll see:

```
you@ubuntu:~$
```

Since you've saved it into the `Downloads` directory which is located in your Home folder, execute `cd Downloads` first:

```
you@ubuntu:~$ cd Downloads
you@ubuntu:~/Downloads$
```

(optional) From that directory, you can run `ls` to verify that the file is there:

```
you@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ls
ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
```

You do not need to make it executable if you use `sh`:

```
you@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo sh ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
```

Comment: @Lekenstyeyn Ok Thatnks for your update I have to go out for a couiple of hours I ill try on my return and paste a report and copy you. Thanks

Comment: @Lekenstyeyn Hi I think I already stated in the question that sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run doesnt work. But something about your instructions are different because the driver has run..so... sudo sh ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run as you have written..gives created directory Fglrx........

Comment: a whole series of dots detected configuration: architechture: i686 (32-bit)...x server: x.org 6.9 or later ....you are running a x86 machine with libc5...No I have choices 1) install driver 8.92 on X.Org 6.9 or later....2.) Generate Distribution Specific Driver Package ..... I now hit the choice 1 and some Y keys and its runs. I then asked to run aticonfig but I think I need to reboot...

Comment: It says THis program must be run as root hen no X server is active... so I have come out of donloads to antony@antony and entered sudo aticonfig --initial... response is found fglrx primary device section...using /etc/X11/xorg.conf..saving back-up to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.fglrx-0....

Comment: results IT wORKS!!!!!!  Ho can I give you a vote of 100?? Many other so called experts here Bruno Pereira to name 1 told me it as not possile as my card as not on the list.. Thank you..Please make yourself available to help the many many people here ho are having this problem..Thanks again..no I only need to fix the wifi and I am running.. I dont think I will bother to go up to 64b for no as I wont remember all this proceedure again...

Comment: @Lekenstyeyn Hi Last night everything was running fine. However no wifi so I used external wifi modem. I tried to update driver via driver hardware applet it ran to 75% and then gave a fail. Now this morning she wont boot anymore. I cant even see netbook on HDMI. Can you advise if I can backstep via sudo or something? Or if to re-install driver and if so how. Or how to check in a window what is wrong. On boot she gives Stopping automatic crash report generation =Fail..She gets to starting save kernal messages=OK.. Thanks

Comment: @Antony What driver did have you tried to update? If possible, boot on a Live CD (or USB), find the file `var/log/kern.log` on your disk, [paste it](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and provide us the link.

Comment: @Lekenstyeyn  In the driver hardware applet it offered a driver for the graphics card ( that was the original boot problem you helped me resolve) I think it was for 3D.. Stupidly I started installing it. Can you talk me through the process of booting from live cd should I use shift to go to the installation menu or what do you need me to do? Thanks

Comment: @Lekenstyeyn Meanwhile I went into restore mode and after antony@antony password etc entered var/log/kern.log...Got -bash:var/log/kern.log: No such file or directory.. how should I enter it? thanks

Comment: @Lekenstyen.. Hi I am getting Login incorect or pemission denied?? Could this be part of the problem? Thanks

Comment: It's the part relative to your root directory. If you boot into recovery mode, it's `/var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: @Lekenstyen Hi did it.. I get 'permission denied' doesnt seem right maybe its part of my problem?

Comment: It's not an executable, get the contents of the file and post it on http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2091/discussion-between-lekensteyn-and-antony)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at the Ubuntu official guide, specifically at the section about how to manually install the ati driver:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Please note that the section is for Ati 11.2, but it should work for the newest one. Or you can take a look an ati driver unofficial guide for Ubuntu 11.10:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide

Here is another unofficial guide on how to install ati driver 11.12 on Ubuntu 11.10:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-1112-linux.html

If you get an error on the commands you listed above, you have not selected the correct folder in which you downloaded the driver or the name of the file is not correct.

Comment: Thnaks  I have to go out for a couple of hours I ill try on my return and paste a report and copy you. But just to complicate things at the moment I dont have wifi driver orking either Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fix here is to download the ATI driver and mane a note of its name, the go in on restore
Login
then cd /home/username/Downloads
Then
Sudo sh attui-driver-installer-name of file
be patient and you will be able to install the ATI driver and it will work after